# Framework code and resources as sibling directory of main project directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'll try my best to be clear with my question, but please, bear with me if there's something obscure.

I'm developing a few PHP web projects. They all share some common code - let's call it a "framework" for the sake of brevity. So I came to the conclusion that it's best to move the framework out of the project directory. In other words, this is what I have now:

```
www
|--framework
|--project1
|--project2
|--project3
```

This works as long as I only need to include PHP scripts. In fact, functions like `require` and `include` use the physical address of a file, and can easily be pointed to the framework using `require_once("../framework/file.php")`.

However, in the framework directory there are also some resources: Javascript files, some functional CSS, and so on. For example, assume jQuery's file is inside the framework dir; **how would I include it**? `<script src="../framework/jquery.min.js"></script>` doesn't work, because a URL like `http://example.com/../framework/jquery.min.js` is considered invalid.

A not-so-cool workaround that crossed my mind is to use mod_rewrite to redirect all requests for `framework` URLs to a "framework include script", a special PHP script that would catch the right file and return its contents. It could work, but it seems pretty much an ugly solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regularily do that by using symlinks:

- If you have shell access to the server run `ln -s ../framework/ .` inside each project directory
- if you do not have shell access, run `<?php symlink('../framework', './framework'); ?>` once inside every project direcory.

**EDIT**

You would then use `<script src="framework/jquery.min.js"></script>`  respe. `<?php include 'framework/something.php'; ?>` to include the framework scripts.

Comment: This seems to go in the right direction, but I can't use symlink under Windows. As of now, all my development takes place on a Windows machine (though the server is Linux-based). 
Also, would you mind being a bit clearer in your edit? Do you mean I can go with plain old links and URLs?

Comment: Plain old links and URLs is exactly what I mean - that's the beauty of it.

Comment: You can use symlinks in Windows - see `mklink` or http://sourceforge.net/projects/symlink-creator/